# Does the fact that data members in a base class are present in a derived class lead to memory wastage?

Tags: c++, oop

Consider this code:

```
class A
{
private:
    int a,b;    
public:
    void getA(){ cout << a << b; }
    void setA(int n1,int n2){ a = n1; b = n2; }
};

class B : public A
{
private:
    int c;
};

int main(){
  B b1;
  b1.setA();
  b1.getA();
  return 0;
}
```

The statement `B b1;` creates the object, consuming memory for `int` `a` and `b` (which are declared in class `A`). If I just want to use only `b` then the memory pertinent to `a` is wasted. Doesn't this lead to memory wastage; particularly in large programs?

Comment: What would `b1.setA();` do if `b` didn't have access to `A::a`?

Comment: Yes and no, because that means the class hierarchy is poorly designed.

Comment: no I want to use some of them, but not all of them in my derived class, my point is doesn't it lead to wastage of memory?

Comment: Upvoted. Although obvious to a C++ programmer with some experience, the *question* itself is not poor. I don't understand the -6. Let's not discourage questions of this nature.

Answer (score 8):

If you say `B` only needs to access `b` but not `a`, that means the design is wrong and you shouldn't use inheritance in the first place.

Inheritance is a "is-a" relationship. Any `B` is an `A`, and then some. If `B` only uses some members of some `A` object, consider just passing that member as a parameter or decoupling `B` and `A` (use a pointer to an `A` inside `B`). **Don't use inheritance just to make it easier to access members.**

So the answer is yes, it is a memory waste, but only because it's designed poorly.

Comment: Another option would be to refactor the common parts into a class which both `A` and `B` will then derive from.

Comment: @Angew only if it makes sense design-wise. Don't design classes and inherit only so you can use common parts - take the decision based on whether it logically makes sense.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore That's certainly true.

Answer (score 2):

Public inheritance models an Is-A relationship, therefore, if B is an A it must have everything that A has which may include things (data, types, functions, etc...) that are not directly accessible by B.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you do not need all the members of your base class in your derived class, then yes, there will be a waste of memory.

One should probably code in such a manner as to reduce wastage of memory like this.